# Kion signifas "k" ĉi tie?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> konsumiĝi: 1 Iom post iom perdiĝi, neniiĝi: vi ĝemos en la fino, kiam
>   konsumiĝos via karno **k** korpo; li konsumiĝis **k**
>   mortis.[(Vortaro)](http://vortaro.net/#konsumi%C4%9Di)

Kion signifas "k" ĉi tie?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ĝi estas mallongigo por la vorto ["kaj"](http://vortaro.net/#k).